# O que é elemento de fluxo no HTML?

Tags: html5, terminologia, html-tags

O que é elemento de fluxo no HTML? Tentei procurar no google, mas só encontrei uma explicação muito técnica e não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Poderia colocar o link da explicação técnica que encontrou para termos como base do que você acha "muito técnico"?

Comment: Aslan, seria bom você dizer também de onde surguiu a sua dúvida, por exemplo de uma aula na faculdade, ou um termo que vc leu em algum lugar e dar a referência de onde você teve essa dúvida. Acredito que você esteja falando sobre o fluxo mesmo, tipo a ordem que as coisas aparecem, se são em linha ou bloco... Mas pra uma resposta melhor, a pergunta precisa ter mais detalhes.